# Will this List be Garbage Collected?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've heard from peers that garbage collection doesn't happen when there is a reference still lying around to an object.

However, does that also include references to child objects?

For example, say we have this code

```
public class Bar {

       public static Foo foo = getFoo();

       private static Foo getFoo() {
           List<Foo> list = List.of(new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo());
           return list.get(0);
       }
}
```

And then foo is used throughout the program lifecycle.

However, the list is no longer needed, and can be garbage collected. The only thing that cannot be garbage collected is that first Foo.

Does this mean that the list if garbage collected, or can it not be because a object it contains is being used elsewhere(the static Foo foo)?

Also, with checking these memory management related things, is there a way see what's been garbage collected using a debugger in IntelliJ?

Comment: *Does this mean that the list if garbage collected, or can it not be because a object it contains is being used elsewhere(the static Foo foo)?* - It gets garbage collected, because the list exists only inside the method. You return just the first element, so that object won't be garbage collected, everything else will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that the list if garbage collected, or can it not be because a object it contains is being used elsewhere(the static Foo foo)?

The list can be garbage collected. As you say, only the one `Foo` that you keep a reference to is required to stick around. An object isn't retained because *it* references another object; an object is only retained if some other object references *it*.

Put more simply: If B references A, and C also references A, but nothing references B, B is eligible for garbage collection. The fact B references A (which isn't eligible for garbage collection, because C references it) doesn't mean B is kept around.

Comment: accepted due to the if B references... explanation. david's answer is good too, this one is just very slightly more comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a local variable and the object that it references is not referenced by another object living beyond this method scope. So when `getFoo()` returns the `List` object is eligible to be garbage collected.
Only the first element of the list will not be eligible to be GC as the `foo` field references  it.